# GUI application using c++ on Linux/Windows

Tags: c++, user-interface

I need to develop a GUI application using C++ on Linux or Windows.
My question is, which language is the best along with C++ for making a GUI application on Linux or Windows?

Is the language usage changes largely from Linux to windows?
And please suggest a language which supports GUI development in C++ which I can learn in around a month and start off the project soon.
I know qt supports such facility. But is that the only framework available?

Comment: Although I develop in Qt for windows and have at times built my Qt applications in linux, I know that wxWidgets is another choice.

Comment: *"which language"* or which *GUI Library*? You specify C++, but also ask to recommend a language. Please clarify.

Comment: Do you want to know other languages than C++ or other frameworks that support cross platform development? These are two totally different things.

Comment: Okay. There I was mixing it up. I wanted to ask Is QT the only Library available for GUI development in c++ ? I meant Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing terms here.

GUI development can be done in C++ using several libraries, to include QT and wxWidgets.

http://qt.nokia.com/

http://www.wxwidgets.org/

GUI on Windows can be created with several other libraries including the Win32 API, MFC, WinForms (.NET), Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF., .NET). etc.

Comment: True, win32 is available for Windows. I believe the OP is looking for cross platform solutions.

Comment: I guess win32 can be somewhat cross platform if you verify that your application works with wine.

Comment: @drescherjm correct. I think if we list every GUI library for the OP... we will run down a very deep and never ending rat-hole. :)